# Python: get output from a command line which exits with nonzero exit code

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, windows-server-2008-r2, stderr

I am Using `Python 2.7.1` on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 box.

I'm trying to get the output of a command line process which gives a nonzero exit status after outputting the information I need.

I was initially using `subprocess.check_output`, and catching the CalledProcessError which occurs with nonzero exit status, but while the returncode was stored in the error, no output revealed this.

Running this against cases which give output but have an exit status of 0 works properly and I can get the output using subprocess.check_output.

My assumption was that the output was being written to STDOUT but the exception pulls its 'output' from STDERR. I've tried to re implement the functionality of check_output, but I still get nothing on the output when I believe I should be seeing output to STDOUT and STDERR. My current code is below (where 'command' is the full text, including parameters, of command I am running:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
output = process.communicate()
retcode = process.poll()
if retcode:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, image_check, output=output)
    return output
```

This gives me the following in the variable output: `[('', None)]`

Is my `subprocess.Popen` code correct?

Comment: after `.communicate()`, you could use `process.returncode` directly instead of `process.poll()`.

Comment: How to get output from the commandline with Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456745/445131

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You code works fine. Turns out that the process that you are calling is probably outputing to  CON. See the following example

```
import subprocess

def check_output(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    output = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, command, output=output[0])
    return output 

command = "echo this>CON"

print "subprocess -> " + subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
print "native -> " + str(check_output(command))

try:
    subprocess.check_output("python output.py", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "subproces CalledProcessError.output = " + e.output

try:
    check_output("python output.py")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "native CalledProcessError.output = " + e.output
```

Output

```
subprocess -> 
native -> ('', None)
stderr subproces CalledProcessError.output = stdout
native CalledProcessError.output = stderr stdout
```

Sadly, I do not know how to resolve the issue. Notice that `subprocess.check_output` results contains only the output from stdout. Your check_output replacement would output both stderr and stdout.

After inspecting `subprocess.check_output`, it does indeed generate a CalledProcessError with the output containing only stdout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is where it is going. I was able to get in touch with the vendor and found out abotu some additional undocumented parameters that strop the nonzero exit statuses from occurring, so my scripting is working now, although I would still like to know how to capture output from CON.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as mentioned in the python doc page:

> To also capture standard error in the result, use
>   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT:

Here is a test code:

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_output('>&2 echo "errrrr"; exit 1', shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print 'e.output: ', e.output


try:
    subprocess.check_output('>&2 echo "errrrr"; exit 1', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print 'e.output: ', e.output
```

output:

```
errrrr
e.output:  
e.output:  errrrr
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue here that might be hitting you-
http://bugs.python.org/issue9905