# How to get data from command line from within a Python program?

Tags: python, command-line, pipe

I want to run a command line program from within a python script and get the output.

How do I get the information that is displayed by foo so that I can use it in my script?

For example, I call `foo file1` from the command line and it prints out

```
Size: 3KB
Name: file1.txt
Other stuff: blah
```

How can I get the file name doing something like `filename = os.system('foo file1')`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing command line programs from within python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess

command = ['ls', '-l']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.IGNORE)
text = p.stdout.read()
retcode = p.wait()
```

Then you can do whatever you want with variable `text`: regular expression, splitting, etc.

The 2nd and 3rd parameters of `subprocess.Popen` are optional and can be removed.

Comment: ... where `command` should be `['foo', 'file1', 'file2', ...]`. +1.

Comment: Thanks! So the foo output is all in text... Now how would I get the file name out of that? Is it like an array or something where I can get text[1]? Or can I search through it for "Name:"? Or start at line #2 character #7 thru newline?

Comment: Look at the re module and write a simple regular expression that pulls it in ``pat = re.compile(r'Name:\s+(.*)$') m = pat.search(text) if m: m.group(1)`` (you'll need to add some newlines)

Comment: I just realized that I have to use Python v2.4, which doens't let me do stdout=subprocess.PIPE. How else can one go about doing this?

Comment: subprocess and PIPE should be there in 2.4  - http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/node227.html  the stderr to ignore is missing.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. This is a problem only on Windows. Not sure what the right way to fix it is, but I found some workarounds.

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'IGNORE'

Comment: It is better to use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, then `stdout_data, stderr_data = p.communicate()`, then `stdout_data, stderr_data = stdout_data.decode('utf-8'), stderr_data.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get the output of a tool called through your Python script is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module in the standard library. Have a look at [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("echo \"foo\"", shell=True)
'foo\n'
```

(If your tool gets input from untrusted sources, make sure not to use the `shell=True` argument.)

Comment: @PrakashPandey this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420990/subprocess-check-output-return-code

Answer (score 2):

This is typically a subject for a bash script that you can run in python :

```
#!/bin/bash
# vim:ts=4:sw=4

for arg; do
    size=$(du -sh "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
    date=$(stat -c "%y" "$arg")
    cat<<EOF
Size: $size
Name: ${arg##*/}
Date: $date 
EOF

done
```

**Edit : How to use it** : open a pseuso-terminal, then copy-paste this :

```
cd
wget http://pastie.org/pastes/2900209/download -O info-files.bash
```

In python2.4 :

```
import os
import sys

myvar = ("/bin/bash ~/info-files.bash '{}'").format(sys.argv[1])
myoutput = os.system(myvar) # myoutput variable contains the whole output from the shell
print myoutput
```

Comment: I know nothing about bash. How do I use this with Python?

Comment: This solution is for Linux only or Windows too if you have Cygwin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin
If you are using windows or if you want a portable solution, see my new post

Answer (score 2):

refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

```
from subprocess import run
o = run("python q2.py",capture_output=True,text=True)
print(o.stdout)
```

the output will be encoded

```
from subprocess import run
o = run("python q2.py",capture_output=True)
print(o.stdout)
```

base syntax

```
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

here output will not be encoded
just a tip

Answer (score 1):

This is a portable solution in pure python :

```
import os
import stat
import time

# pick a file you have ...
file_name = 'll.py'
file_stats = os.stat(file_name)

# create a dictionary to hold file info
file_info = {
    'fname': file_name,
    'fsize': file_stats [stat.ST_SIZE],
    'f_lm': time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",time.localtime(file_stats[stat.ST_MTIME])),
}


print("""
Size: {} bytes
Name: {}
Time: {}
 """
).format(file_info['fsize'], file_info['fname'], file_info['f_lm'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, You can pass a plain OS command with spaces, subquotes and newlines into the `subcommand` module so we can parse the response text like this:

1. Save this into test.py:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import subprocess

   command = ('echo "this echo command' + 
   ' has subquotes, spaces,\n\n" && echo "and newlines!"')

   p = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, 
   shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   text = p.stdout.read()
   retcode = p.wait()
   print text;
   ```
2. Then run it like this:

   ```
   python test.py
   ```
3. Which prints:

   ```
   this echo command has subquotes, spaces,


   and newlines!
   ```

If this isn't working for you, it could be troubles with the python version or the operating system.  I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10 for this example.