# subprocess.check_output return code

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using:

```
grepOut = subprocess.check_output("grep " + search + " tmp", shell=True)
```

To run a terminal command, I know that I can use a try/except to catch the error but how can I get the value of the error code?

I found this on the official documentation:

```
 exception subprocess.CalledProcessError

    Exception raised when a process run by check_call() or check_output() returns a non-zero exit status.

    returncode

        Exit status of the child process.
```

But there are no examples given and Google was of no help.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can get the error code and results from the exception that is raised.

This can be done through the fields `returncode` and `output`.

For example:

```
import subprocess

try:
    grepOut = subprocess.check_output("grep " + "test" + " tmp", shell=True)                       
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as grepexc:                                                                                                   
    print("error code", grepexc.returncode, grepexc.output)
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I wanted. But now I am wondering, is there a way to get a return code without a try/except? IE just get the return code of the check_output, whether it is 0 or 1 or other is not important to me and I don't actually need to save the output.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, check_output will always throw CalledProcessError as long as an error code is non-zero. This means that if you don't want the program to suddenly terminate, you will need a try/except clause. You can however just use a "pass" statement when you get to the except clause if you don't care about the error code.

Answer (score 50):

Python 3.5 introduced the [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) method. The signature looks like:

```
subprocess.run(
  args, 
  *, 
  stdin=None, 
  input=None, 
  stdout=None, 
  stderr=None, 
  shell=False, 
  timeout=None, 
  check=False
)
```

The returned result is a [`subprocess.CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess). In 3.5, you can access the `args`, `returncode`, `stdout`, and `stderr` from the executed process.

Example:

```
>>> result = subprocess.run(['ls', '/tmp'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
>>> result.returncode
0

>>> result = subprocess.run(['ls', '/nonexistent'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
>>> result.returncode
2
```

Comment: I reckon this is the most up-to-date approach. The syntax is much more simple and intuitive and was probably added for just that reason.

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run:
"If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a CalledProcessError exception will be raised. Attributes of that exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if they were captured."

Answer (score 37):

> is there a way to get a return code without a try/except?

`check_output` raises an exception if it receives non-zero exit status because it frequently means that a command failed. `grep` may return non-zero exit status even if there is no error -- you could use `.communicate()` in this case:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pattern, filename = 'test', 'tmp'
p = Popen(['grep', pattern, filename], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          bufsize=-1)
output, error = p.communicate()
if p.returncode == 0:
   print('%r is found in %s: %r' % (pattern, filename, output))
elif p.returncode == 1:
   print('%r is NOT found in %s: %r' % (pattern, filename, output))
else:
   assert p.returncode > 1
   print('error occurred: %r' % (error,))
```

You don't need to call an external command to filter lines, you could do it in pure Python:

```
with open('tmp') as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'test' in line:
            print line,
```

If you don't need the output; you could use `subprocess.call()`:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL # Python 3
except ImportError: # Python 2
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)

returncode = call(['grep', 'test', 'tmp'], 
                  stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Answer (score 4):

To get both output and return code (without try/except) simply use [subprocess.getstatusoutput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) (Python 3 required)

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write a good answer.

Comment: Done. Now what?

Comment: Its not just reading, its about implementing it on your answer.

Comment: I guess I just don't see what's wrong with it. Please tell me how you think it should be improved.

Comment: You could provide an example of the method you mentioned being used. However, your answer brought another method to my attention that I didn't know about yet so it's already been valuable to me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 - use [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput) module:

```
import command
rc, out = commands.getstatusoutput("ls missing-file")
if rc != 0: print "Error occurred: %s" % out
```

In Python 3 - use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) module:

```
import subprocess
rc, out = subprocess.getstatusoutput("ls missing-file")
if rc != 0: print ("Error occurred:", out)
```

> Error occurred: ls: cannot access missing-file: No such file or directory

Comment: This is the best option. `subprocess.run()` may throw exceptions if the command is not found on the machine (e.g. `nvcc`). This approach will hide all of that in the returncode and not throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since Python 3.5 it is better to use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) :

```
import subprocess

grepOut = subprocess.run(['grep', search, 'tmp'], shell=True) ## Only use shell=True if necessary
```

This will generate a `subprocess.CompletedProcess` instance which will be stored at `grepOut`. Then, and finally answering your question, you can get the return value from `subprocess.run()` like this:

```
grepOut.returncode
```

which will be equal to `0` if the command was successful, and not equal to `0` if it failed.

Finally, for completeness sake, you could even handle the error by means of a try/except block using the method [check_returncode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.check_returncode) from `subprocess.CompletedProcess` class:

```
try:
    ## Add argument `capture_output=True` if you want to store the output of the command
    grepOut = subprocess.run(['grep', search, 'tmp'], shell=True)
    grepOut.check_returncode()

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    ## If returncode is non-zero, raise a CalledProcessError and print this message
    print(f"Oops, something went wrong. Error code: {err.returncode}")
```

Hope it is clear enough.