# Python subprocess shell=true custom error message

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, ubuntu-18.04

I am using subprocess in python 3 to use operating system commands (I am on ubuntu 18.04) and I was wondering if there was anyway to make make a custom error message while shell=True

```
import subprocess
command = str('wrong')
try:
   grepOut = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as grepexc:
    print("oops! wrong command")
```

When i run it I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: wrong: not found
oops! wrong command
```

is there any way to remove the "/bin/sh: 1: wrong: not found" message and just have "oops! wrong command"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subprocess.check\_output return code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420990/subprocess-check-output-return-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the shell's error message by redirecting `stderr`, and insert your own by using `check_output` instead of `call`:

```
import subprocess
import os

command = str('wrong command')
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=devnull)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("oops! wrong command")
    output = ""

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! Although, I noticed that when command  is an actual command such as, command  = ' echo Ubuntu!' I get no output

Comment: I tested that exact scenario and it worked fine for me, but now I see that's only true in the REPL! I've updated the answer to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help!