# Scipy in Abaqus

Tags: python, scipy, abaqus

I would like to create a Python script for Abaqus in which Scipy library will be used. Unfortunately, Abaqus doesn't have that library. It could be installed but I would like to do it differently.

My idea is to write a function which will take arguments, pass it to new Python interpreter opened outside Abaqus and then it returns the output to my file.

I am pretty sure it might be done but I am still learning Python. Please give me any hint I could used to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to start a background process, which will execute a Python script. This can be done in Python via a built-in [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

In the simplest case, you would write something like this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'your_script_name.py'])
process.wait() # If you want to stop caller until callee terminates
```

It is also possible to retrieve results returned by sub process, but you can read more about it in other threads:

- [shell -python getoutput() equivalent in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess)
- [How to get data from command line from within a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217613/how-to-get-data-from-command-line-from-within-a-python-program?rq=1)

Just be aware that, in some cases, it is necessary to modify the contents of dictionary containing environment variables (`os.environ`) by removing Abaqus specific environment variables. Otherwise there are some issues starting a sub process.

If you do want to pass modified environment to a new process, `Popen` has an argument `env`.